# "Man, it's not that easy!" - What if I'm talking to a woman?

Tags: indian-english, informal-language

We use the word *'man'* in such context quite commonly.

[Added note: To avoid ambiguity] In all these cases, I'm **talking to a man**. He's right there, in front of me.

> *"**Man**, it's not that easy!"* 
>   *"Look **man**, don't mess with me."* 
>  *"Ah, bang on, **man**!"*

What if I'm talking to a woman? Can I still use 'man' as 'guys' (which is now considered as an epicene term)? I can call girls 'guys' informally.

Comment: To exclaim "Man, it's not that easy!" is not really a form of address. But "Look man, don't mess with me." *is* a form of address.  Its counterpart (in the same register) is "Look, lady, don't mess with me."

Comment: I've heard *dude* used this way to refer to women. Oddly, it is common to address a group of women as *guys* but I don't think I've heard the singular *guy* used to refer to a woman.

Answer (score 4):

"Man" here is not an address to the person you are speaking to, but an exclamation, like "wow" or "oh no". Taken literally, it makes little sense -- who is this "man" that we are referring to? But interjections rarely make literal sense. People often use vulgar words in exactly the same role, like "Oh [fecal matter], that wasn't easy!" Or, "Oh [sexual act], that wasn't easy!" Those make little sense if you try to interpret them literally either.

Comment: No, in the first expression, I'm warning my friend. It's a conversation and I'm not talking to myself.

Comment: @Maulik: Obviously *intonation* would affect interpretation of your intended sense for ***Man*** in example #1. But in the absence of that native speakers would tend to assume an "exclamation", because it doesn't really work as an address to a female. The same situation arises with ***Brother*** (not so common as an exclamation today, particularly in the shortened form ***Bro***, which imho would almost *never* be used as a female term of address).

Comment: In the context of "Man, it's not that easy!", is "Man" a less profane substitute for "God" or "Goddamn" or "Damnit"?  If so, "Man" is being used in the sense of "Mankind" or "Jesus was the Son of Man".

Comment: @Jasper I just did some searching for the origins of the interjection and found nothing conclusive. Short answer: I don't think anyone knows. We have similar interjections "brother" and "boy", as in, "Oh man is it hot today", "Oh brother is it hot today", and "Oh boy is it hot today" being pretty much interchangeable. It's a stretch to theorize that "man" is short for "son of man"; I think it's even more of a stretch to suppose that "boy" is derived from any reference to God or Jesus. One could speculate endlessly, of course.

Comment: @maulikv Few people today address others as "man". I suppose that was done in the 60s -- "Hey man, what's happening?" -- but it's pretty much unheard of today. Most English speakers would find it extremely odd. Like addressing someone as "human". My first thought would be that this is a science fiction move and you are an alien: "What do you call your planet, human?"

Comment: @Jay -- Thank you for looking into it.  I don't think that "Man" is short for "Son of Man".  Rather, I was suggesting that "Man" is complementary to "God", just like "Son of Man" and "Son of God" are complementary descriptions of Jesus.  For purposes of the interjection, it might not be a coincidence that "man" sounds a lot like "damn".  As you note, this is all speculation.

Comment: @Jasper Ah, I misunderstood what you were trying to say. I suppose that when people are taking an oath, some who do not believe in God or who believe it inappropriate to invoke God, instead of saying, "I swear to God ...", will say, "I swear by my honor ...", etc. So by that reasoning someone might say that instead of shouting "Oh God, this is horrible", he will shout "Oh Man, this is horrible." An interesting theory, I think. I have zero evidence to confirm or refute it.

Comment: @Jay -- I hear this interjection fairly often, especially by young men, or when overhearing conversations among young or middle-aged women.  Before this thread, I thought it was inappropriate when used in conversations where all the listeners are women.  Now that I have thought of the religious angle, I am not so sure.  The women in question tend to be church-going Christians.  I doubt that the women have thought of the religious angle either; they just use "Man" as an interjection to emphasize that something was difficult or impressive.

Comment: Although it has nothing to do with religion, many young and some adult women do say this to each other.  In fact, some younger females say *dude* to each other in the same way.  It's easy for a vocative like this to lose its vocative meaning and become an exclamation—this is an example of what is called "semantic bleaching" in linguistics.

Comment: Oh...it's damn common in India! Even today! Added tag.

Comment: @snailboat I don't think we're disagreeing. "Man" in this context is just an exclamation, so it has nothing to do with the person I am speaking to per se. Like if someone says "God, this lecture is boring", it is unlikely that he is actually addressing God. God presumably already know the lecture is boring. It's just an exclamation.

Comment: @MaulikV In India you call each other "man"? Okay, I was not aware of that, I haven't heard it from Indians I've known in the U.S. I suppose the question then becomes whether "man" is also used as an exclamation in India, in which case the sentence could be ambiguous. In either case, as I wasn't aware that Indians use "man" as a form of address, I can't say whether it applies to women or what the alternative would be when addressing a woman. I yield to someone more knowledgeable about Indian English.

Comment: @Jay Oh, yes, I generally agree with your answer, and in fact I've already upvoted it.  My comment was mostly prompted by Jasper's idea that it might be connected to religion somehow.

Answer (score 2):

For informal use, it's becoming more common. However, it isn't practiced or commonplace in formal or most professional settings.

*Man* isn't always gender-specific. *Male* and *female* are, and a female man is more frequently identified as a *wo**man***. I've also heard females addressed as *dude* among the younger generation, even though that word is traditionally masculine.

Even in the Bible, man isn't specifically masculine. "So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them." Genesis 1:27, King James Version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the same sentences with a "woman" because "man" here is part of this common expression. Using "woman" make no sense!

The women themselves get what you mean because they are aware of this common expression!